# Change both placeholder and value of BootStrapVue forms via innerHTML

Tags: javascript, forms, vue.js, innerhtml

Let's suppose we have defined a simple form using bootstrapvue with only one field:

```
 <div id="myForm">
    <b-form-group horizontal :label-cols="4" required label="Specify the date"> 
          <b-form-datepicker v-model.trim="date"></b-form-datepicker>
        </b-form-group>
</div>
```

When a certain button is clicked in my application, a JavaScript function gets invoked (let's call it *functA*). What I'm trying to do is, change both the value and placeholder of the date field in the form (via *innerhtml*).

So it would be something like this:

```
functA(newPlaceHolder) {   //This function's intended behavior is to change the date field placeholder in the form
document.getElementById("myForm").innerHTML=' [...]change the placeholder of the attribute *date* so that it uses the one passed as parameter to the function';

}
```

How could this be done? I've tried several things before, but none of them working.

Thank you very much for your attention.

Answer (score 2):

I think you are referring to the div by calling getElementById, however, the div is not a placeholder for text so you should call getElementById("").innerHTML on an attribute that holds text.

Comment: Hi notrayen, thanks for your answer. So, should I assign a certain ID to the date attribute inside the form? How could it be done?

Comment: yeah, assign an ID to the attribute that holds your date, and then just call getElementById. I advise you to check the documentation further.